# promscale-extension fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found

Tags: freebsd, compiling, postgresql

I'm attempting to compile `promscale-extension` for PostgreSQL 14.5 on FreeBSD 13.1, but I keep getting `fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found`. I've verified that the file `/usr/local/include/libintl.h` exists, and that the error occurs with both promscale-extension 0.6.0 and 0.7.0. Does anyone know how to remedy this, or should I report a bug?

The complete error message is

```
…
 Compiling pgx-pg-sys v0.4.5 (https://github.com/timescale/pgx?rev=96ece243#96ece243)
error: failed to run custom build command for `pgx-pg-sys v0.4.5 (https://github.com/timescale/pgx?rev=96ece243#96ece243)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/usr/home/dave/Repos/promscale/promscale_extension/target/release/build/pgx-pg-sys-23463da5d8c5cde1/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PGX_PG_SYS_GENERATE_BINDINGS_FOR_RELEASE
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=/home/dave/.pgx/config.toml
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/pg10.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/pg11.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/pg12.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/pg13.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/pg14.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=cshim/pgx-cshim.c
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=cshim/Makefile

  --- stderr
  manifest_dir=/home/dave/.cargo/git/checkouts/pgx-86cb45baab31d1a6/96ece24/pgx-pg-sys
  shim_src=/home/dave/.cargo/git/checkouts/pgx-86cb45baab31d1a6/96ece24/pgx-pg-sys/cshim
  shim_dst=/usr/home/dave/Repos/promscale/promscale_extension/target/release/build/pgx-pg-sys-938b3b40f8fb0d27/out/cshim
  Generating bindings for pg14
  /usr/local/include/postgresql/server/c.h:75:10: fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found
  /usr/local/include/postgresql/server/c.h:75:10: fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found, err: true
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to generate bindings for pg14: ()', /home/dave/.cargo/git/checkouts/pgx-86cb45baab31d1a6/96ece24/pgx-pg-sys/build.rs:530:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
gmake: *** [Makefile:99: package] Error 1
```